# Measure distance between two points

Tags: point, distance, formula

I want to code some converter in C# (I need it for a project), where I get two (or more) coordinate pairs from QGIS, in decimal degree pair format (47.xxxx,19.xxxx).
I need to measure the distance between two pairs, and return the result in Meters (with decimal).
I am new to GIS, and so far I only figured out that 0.00012 is roughly 10 meters. But I want my program to be more precise than this.

How can this be calculated?

Does it have any formula?

I need an accuracy of at least 1/10th of a meter (but cm accuracy would be really nice).

Comment: Computing the distance between two lat/lon points on a spheroid is a partial differential equation only solvable through iterative means. It is the second of the two Problems of [Geodesy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy), known as the Inverse (or Reverse) Problem. While it is possible to code your own, you'd save yourself a ton of debugging if you use a geodetic computation library.

Comment: 1 degree from East to West is rougly 110 km. At the Equator. At the Polar Circle that's only 36 km. So you figured wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use Karney's GeographicLib see https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I looked at it it seems nice, but a bit overkill for my needs. 
I kept digging on MSDN and found this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location?view=netframework-4.8
It's way not that complex, but for a simple distance calculation, it's good. It needs two decimal coordinates and returns the distance in meters. Just what I needed. 

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.device.location?view=netframework-4.8

It's not as feature-packed as GeographicLib, but for simple distance calculation, it's more than enough.